# how to run a javascript function asynchronously, without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, rhino, parallel-processing

its a server side Javascript (rhino engine), so setTimeout is not available. how to run a function asynchronously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `Multithreaded Script Execution` example on the [Rhino Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Examples#Multithreaded_Script_Execution) page. Basically, JavaScript does not support threading directly, but you may be able to use a Java thread to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 42):

You can use [`java.util.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [`java.util.TimerTask`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to roll your own set/clear Timeout and set/clear Interval functions:

```
var setTimeout,
    clearTimeout,
    setInterval,
    clearInterval;

(function () {
    var timer = new java.util.Timer();
    var counter = 1; 
    var ids = {};

    setTimeout = function (fn,delay) {
        var id = counter++;
        ids[id] = new JavaAdapter(java.util.TimerTask,{run: fn});
        timer.schedule(ids[id],delay);
        return id;
    }

    clearTimeout = function (id) {
        ids[id].cancel();
        timer.purge();
        delete ids[id];
    }

    setInterval = function (fn,delay) {
        var id = counter++; 
        ids[id] = new JavaAdapter(java.util.TimerTask,{run: fn});
        timer.schedule(ids[id],delay,delay);
        return id;
    }

    clearInterval = clearTimeout;

})()
```

Comment: Whit your code snippet, i was able to run Jasmine tests inside Rhino without the need of EnvJS. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could give you 100 upvotes, very awesome. Thanks so much.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! To be fully compatibile with browsers, you need to handle omission of delay as well. MDN says that the minium delay as per the HTML5 spec is 4ms, so add the following: if (delay == null) { delay = 4; }

Comment: @DaveParoulek You can give a bounty to Weston ;)

Comment: **NOTA:** Rhino 1.7R4 has a bug that prevents the code in this answer to run. Either downgrade to 1.7R3 or use a newer version. (Check this discussion for details on newer versions: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla-rhino/6vvcjg_7NNU/XnWEPEyfcfwJ)

Comment: @Alex, I created version that uses `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `Timer` and works in 1.7R4: https://gist.github.com/nbeloglazov/9633318

Answer (score 3):

Another version using [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), compatible with Rhino 1.7R4 and proposed by [@Nikita-Beloglazov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575421/nikita-beloglazov):

```
var setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval, clearInterval;

(function () {
    var executor = new java.util.concurrent.Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    var counter = 1;
    var ids = {};

    setTimeout = function (fn,delay) {
        var id = counter++;
        var runnable = new JavaAdapter(java.lang.Runnable, {run: fn});
        ids[id] = executor.schedule(runnable, delay, 
            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return id;
    }

    clearTimeout = function (id) {
        ids[id].cancel(false);
        executor.purge();
        delete ids[id];
    }

    setInterval = function (fn,delay) {
        var id = counter++;
        var runnable = new JavaAdapter(java.lang.Runnable, {run: fn});
        ids[id] = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, delay, delay, 
            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return id;
    }

    clearInterval = clearTimeout;

})()
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/nbeloglazov/9633318