# Javascript: How to write a function that will be executed asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, web-worker

I have a few lines of code that I want to run asynchronously in Javascript so that it doesn't slow down my main algorithm. See this pseudo code:

```
//main algorithm with critical code that should run as soon as possible
...
...
runInParallel(function(){
  //time consuming unimportant code to shows some progress feedback to user
  ...
}
//the rest of the time critical algorithm
...
...
runInParallel(function(){
  //time consuming unimportant code to shows some progress feedback to user
  ...
}
//and so on and so forth
```

I searched Stackoverflow for how to write asynchronous code in Javascript but the following questions are not similar to mine:

- [how to run a javascript function asynchronously, without using setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261705/how-to-run-a-javascript-function-asynchronously-without-using-settimeout): it's about server side
- [Loading javascript asynchronously - How to do callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557565/loading-javascript-asynchronously-how-to-do-callbacks): it's about loading source code

I guess I can use timers for this purpose. All I want is the body of the function runInParallel() that runs a code efficiently in parallel with my main algorithm with lower priority if possible. Anyone?

Comment: lower priority? I doubt is there such a way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript has no synchronization / thread management. If you wish to execute something asynchronously, you can use `setTimeout` combined with a callback to be notified when the function 's finished.

```
 var asyncHandle = setTimeout(function () { asyncCode(); callback(); }, 10);
```

The `asyncHandle` can be used to cancel the timeout prior to the function being called.

Comment: these methods are quite obsolete, as from the introduction of web workers (see my post).

Comment: I don't agree. Why should you limit your support to HTML 5 enabled clients for such a trivial thing?

Comment: one can argue about the adoption of web standards as means of enforcing acceptance by the browser vendors, but this is a whole other issue..

Comment: I agree that something 's got to give, but most of the web is not HTML 5, so in the end, I guess you 'll be hurting your app by limiting its audience, rather than enforcing some standard.

Comment: We have strict control over the runtime environment and we have HTML5 there. But I think Web Workers are too big for the problem that we have at the moment. For now I think this setTimeout() will do the job. However I agree that Web Workers may be the ultimate answer if our problem expands.

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting HTML5 supporting browsers, go with [HTML5 Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/).

You can also try this interesting, but quite old [JavaScript compiler](http://neilmix.com/narrativejs/doc/index.html) that allows a language extension for this purpose.